# At least one cell in a range is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if  specific range (L32,M32;N32;O32;P32;Q32,R32;S32;T32).

If one of the cells is not empty a message should be displayed "FSFV check".

```vb
For Each cell In Range("L32:T32")
    If cell.Value <>  "" Then
        MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA"
    Else
    
    End If          
Next
    
End Sub
```

It displays the message eight times but I only want it once.

Comment: You might want to read up on the Excel CountA method which would have been revealed if you had been bothered to google 'count empty cells in Excel range'

Comment: or put the statement `Exit Sub` after the `MsgBox`-statement to leave the loop.

Answer (score 1):

### If a Cell in a Range Is Blank...

If you're practicing loops, you could do the following.

```vb
Sub Test1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ws.Range("L32:T32").Cells
        If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = 0 Then  ' cell is blank
            MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit For ' blank cell found, stop looping
            ' Or:
            'Exit Sub ' blank cell found, stop looping
        End If
    Next cell

    ' With 'Exit For' you'll end up here
    ' and you could continue with the sub.

End Sub
```

If not, rather use the following.

```vb
Sub Test2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    If Application.CountBlank(ws.Range("L32:T32")) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA", _
            vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

**Hardly Related But Interesting**

If you were wondering what happens to an object-type *Control* variable (in this case `cell`) in a *For Each...Next* loop when the loop has finished uninterrupted, the following example proves that it is set to `Nothing`.

```
Sub Test3()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim cell As Range
 
    For Each cell In ws.Range("L32:T32").Cells
        If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next cell
    
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Continuing...", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
Sub Test()

Dim AnyData As Integer

AnyData = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("L32:T32"))

If AnyData = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you the simplest approach:

```
Dim Found As Boolean
Found = False
For Each cell In Range("L32:T32")
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        Found = True
    End If
Next
If Found Then
    MsgBox "Check with CRA if FSFV was performed and notify RA"
End If
```

As you see, the fact that you have found an empty cell is kept in a `Boolean` variable, and afterwards you just use that information for showing your messagebox.

Comment: Many thanks all and many thanks Dominique, it solved exactly my problem :-)

Comment: I'm glad to see that I could help, please accept my answer for reference purposes.